# Como posso adicionar um hífen entre todos os números pares de um valor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom dia, alguem poderia me ajudar com um código por favor, estou precisando inserir um hífens (-) entre dois números pares. Por exemplo, se receber o número 02368859 como entrada, a saída do programa deverá ser: 0-236-8-859
Eu fiz assim, mas está com erro.

```
num = input("Digite um número:")

def separador(num):
    num = list(num)
    fim = 1
    i = 0
    saida=''
    while i <len(num):
        if int(num[i])%2==0:
            saida+=num[i]
            if int(num[fim])%2==0:
                 saida+='-'
            i+=1
            fim+=1
        else:
            saida+=num[i]
            i+=1
            fim+=1        
    print(saida)

separador(num)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Expressões Regulares

Você consegue fazer isso com expressões regulares:

```
([02468]{2,})
```

Captura qualquer sequência formada pelos números 0, 2, 4, 6 ou 8 com dois ou mais de tamanho. Após capturar as sequências de números pares basta substituir por ela mesma adicionando o hífen:

```
'-'.join(grupo_capturado)  # '-'.join('28') = '2-8'
```

Assim, o código fica:

```
import re

def adiciona_separador(matches):
    return '-'.join(matches.group(0))

resultado = re.sub(r'([02468]{2,})', adiciona_separador, '02368859')

print(resultado)  # 0-236-8-859
```

Se quiser fazer uma função para isso:

```
def separador(numero, separador='-'):
    return re.sub(
        r'([02468]{2,})', 
        lambda matches: separador.join(matches.group(0)), 
        numero
    )

print( separador('02368859') )  # 0-236-8-859
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/CooperativeGoodDeskscan) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/PaajG6)</sup>

---

## Forma Iterativa

De forma iterativa, como você tentou fazer, pode percorrer diretamente a *string*, não precisa convertê-la para uma lista. No Python as *strings* são iteráveis também. Você pode iterar sobre os caracteres desta *string* adicionando-os em uma *string* e sempre que encontrar um número par você verifica se o último valor desta *string* também é par, se sim, você adiciona um hífen antes de adicionar o número atual.

```
def separador(entrada):
    resultado = ''

    for caractere in entrada:
        if caractere in '02468':
            if len(resultado) > 0 and resultado[-1] in '02468':
                resultado += '-'
        resultado += caractere

    return resultado

print(separador('02368859'))  # 0-236-8-859
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/InferiorBeigeQuark) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/LQHNrp)</sup>

Comment: Ok, vou estudar ela aqui. Muito obrigado Anderson.

Comment: Show de bola! :)

Comment: Você conseguiu praticamente em uma linha de comando, parabéns. Vejo que tenho que estudar muito ainda.

Comment: @RafaelM. Eu adicionei uma forma que é basicamente o que você fez, só que uma forma mais simplificada.

Comment: Eu estava analisando é faltou um pouco mais de logica na minha. Essa sua ficou simples e boa.

Comment: Se eu fosse fazer esse exercício, minha tentativa inicial seria parecida com a sua abordagem com regex, mas usando lookahead pra inserir os hífens. Exemplo: `re.sub(r'([02468])((?=([02468])))', r'\1-\2', '02368859')`

Comment: @Gabriel Não quer postar esta alternativa como resposta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Feito.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar uma abordagem puramente com regex. O "pulo do gato" é

- Usar lookahead para não perder os padrões sobrepostos.
- Usar backreference para reinserir os dígitos encontrados

Exemplo:

```
import re

resultado = re.sub(r'([02468])((?=([02468])))', r'\1-\2', '02368859')
print(resultado)
```

Leia mais em:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions
- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping

Comment: Vou olhar as referencias Gabriel. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma outra abordagem em Python puro, bastante similar ao código de iteração do @AndersonCalos.

Nela, eu itero cada item que vai do índice 0 ao penúltimo, adicionando este número já à saída. E verifico se tanto o item "a" (índice atual da iteração) como o item "b" (índice atual + 1) são pares. Caso for, também adiciono o "-" entre eles.

Esta seria função:

```py
def separador2(num):
    saida = ''
    pares = '02468'
    for indice in range(len(num)-1):
        saida += num[indice] # Já adiciono o algarismo
        if num[indice] in pares and num[indice+1] in pares: # Se o "indice+1" for par também...
            saida += '-'
    saida += num[-1] #Adiciono o último caractere que eu omiti
    return saida

assert separador2('02368859') == '0-236-8-859'
```

Comment: Me parece que é a mesma lógica sua, mas só que com o laço for ao invés do while.

Comment: Bom dia Breno, gostei da abordagem pura. Muito bom mesmo. Vlw.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz do jeito que o @Breno citou, mas com pequenas modificações para adaptar ao exercicio proposto.

```
num = input("Informe os valores:")
def separador(num):
saida = ''
pares = '02468'

for x in range(len(num)-1):
    saida += num[x]
    if num[x] in pares and num[x+1] in pares:
        saida += '-'
saida += num[-1]
print(saida)


separador(num)
```